# How to get the soap web service data

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have a newbie question about soap. I am trying to get the data from soap web services and I have a link that is provided by the vendor like

```
https://project/services/productLog?wsdl
```

If I enter the url in my browser, I got bunch of soap data returned. I was wondering how do I get the returned data by using php.

The returned data is like

```
...more..

<xs:complexType name="getProduct">
   <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="getProductOwner">
   <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:getID"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

...more
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could use curl to get the data.

Comment: SOAP can be a bit tricky at the beginning. PHP has some build in tools for that. See for an easy tutorial: http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP is quite the pain in the backside when starting off... It would be a good idea to check [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) before starting, as well as some information about how SOAP works.

That being said, the first thing to take into account is that the url you got is actually the WSDL for the web service.
This is the equivalent to a contract which specifies which methods the web service offers and what parameters it needs to do so.

With the wsdl you can create a SoapClient instance which can then be used to call the specific methods. The client in itself is a dynamic object and is automatically created with the same methods specified in the WSDL.

This means that if you want to execute a a method called "getProduct" from the web service, all it would take would be to instance a SoapClient for it and then call **$yourSoapClientInstance->getProduct()**.

Imagine you want to use a method for [this](http://www.gcomputer.net/webservices/dilbert.asmx?wsdl) web service.
The service offers the two methods "TodaysDilbert" and "DailyDilbert". Doing so would be as simple as this:

```
<?php
try {

    $wsdl = "http://www.gcomputer.net/webservices/dilbert.asmx?wsdl"
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);

    $response = $soapClient->TodaysDilbert();

    print "<pre>" . print_r($response, true) . "</pre>";

} catch (SoapFault $f) {
   // Your exception handling
}
?>
```

You should note that if the response from excecuting a SoapClient method is a complex structure, your return value will be an stdClass object containing the whole response's structure.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The data that you see is the actual WSDL file. To make a request to the web service, you will need to use a web service client. The PHP site has some good information in that regard:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php